# Quartz Scheduler getFinalFireTime null even with an expired cron

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I'm using Quartz Scheduler in Java to schedule jobs based on entries in a database. I'm trying to automate disabling those entries when they will never run again, so I don't try to read them every time the application starts.

I have a cron for a very specific date, for example `0 25 12 4 DEC ? 2021`. That is a specific date, it has passed, and cannot ever fire again.

I build a chrontrigger and check `endTrigger.getFinalFireTime()` and it returns null, which I believe should only happen when the cron allows future firing.

```
// Build the end cron trigger
CronTrigger endTrigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
    .withIdentity("eventEndCron", "quartzGroup")
    .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0 25 12 4 DEC ? 2021"))
    .forJob("eventEnd", "quartzGroup")
    .build();
```

If I try to schedule the job, it throws an error `Based on configured schedule, the given trigger 'quartzGroup.eventStartCron' will never fire.`

Why isn't `getFinalFireTime` giving me a date? Is there some other approach I need to use?

Comment: The error message is correct. December 4-th 2021, 00:25 am is already in the past and the trigger will never fire. The question is - are you just trying to get the final fire time, or are you trying to start a timer to schedule it? The [Javadoc](https://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.1.7/org/quartz/Trigger.html#getFinalFireTime()) says "Note that the return time *may* be in the past." It does not say anything about an exception being thrown. If so, you could file a bug report.

Comment: It's in the past on purpose. `getFinalFireTime` should *only* return null when there's indefinite executions left. But this was for a specific date, so the final fire time should literally match the cron. EDIT: The error happens when I try to actually schedule it, which is fine. I should never get to that point though. Why isn't getFinalFireTime working? The docs say `Returns the last time at which the Trigger will fire, if the Trigger will repeat indefinitely, null will be returned.`